# Jquery binding seems to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a jQuery script which is giving me alot of trouble. I'm no expert on the framework, but I've used it successfully in a number of occassions in the past.

I'm trying to setup what amounts to be a subform of a subform. I.e. the user is filling out a questionnaire, based on user input additional form fields show and in this case, based on that input more fields can show.

So in this case I load in a script which searches for the controling elements and binds something to their change event. This approach works on the first form field, but not on another. The content is loaded with the rest of the html, not via ajax. The really weird part is that using a debugger and watching the console I can tell that the script below is finding the elements I want, and tries to call change(), but then the event never fires!

```
$('td.subFormYesControl input.CodebtorParentQuestion').each(function() {
    console.log("Hit");
    //alert($(this).prop('class'));
    $(this).on("change", function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "1") {
            $(this).parents('tbody').eq(0).children('tr.subFormRow').show();
            $(this).parents('tbody').eq(0).siblings('tbody.CodebtorSubForm').show();
        } else {
            $(this).parents('tbody').eq(0).children('tr.subFormRow').hide();
            $(this).parents('tbody').eq(0).siblings('tbody.CodebtorSubForm').hide();
        }
    });
});​
```

I've been doing some trial and error testing with very little luck. If I change this from being wrapped in `$(document).ready()` to `$(window).load()` it works in FF, but not IE.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on???

EDIT: Thanks for all the help! There is alot of generated html in the implementation I'm using, so here is the parent element of the control I'm trying to work with. Let me know if more would be helpful!

```
<td class="subFormYesControl"><input type="radio" value="1" id="c1_CodebtorsParent[0]0" class="CodebtorParentQuestion" name="c1_CodebtorsParent[0]"><label for="c1_CodebtorsParent[0]0">Yes</label><br><input type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" id="c1_CodebtorsParent[0]1" class="CodebtorParentQuestion" name="c1_CodebtorsParent[0]"><label for="c1_CodebtorsParent[0]1">No</label><br></td>
```

EDIT 2: It seems to get more strange, but I think I've found a clue. If I add a simple alert as shown below:

```
        alert($(this).prop('class'));
        $('td.subFormYesControl input.CodebtorParentQuestion').each(function() {


    $(this).on("change", function() {
        console.log($(this).length);
                    if($(this).val() == "1") {
                        $(this).parents('tbody').eq(0).children('tr.subFormRow').show();
                        $(this).parents('tbody').eq(0).siblings('tbody.CodebtorSubForm').show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).parents('tbody').eq(0).children('tr.subFormRow').hide();
                        $(this).parents('tbody').eq(0).siblings('tbody.CodebtorSubForm').hide();
                    }                    
            });
        });
```

The code seems to work! Remove the alert, it stops working!!! Any ideas????

---

Thank you for all the help everyone. I was preparing the jsfiddle and removing a few seemingly unrelated plugins. when I removed one of them, an intellitext tool, the code began working just fine in all browsers. I've gone through testing and was even able to push the code back to document.ready, so I think I'm going to mark it answered and chalk it up to a plugin compatibility issue/bug.

Thanks again everyone

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML or an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: Hi Gordon, I changed the log line to console.log("This.length = " + $(this).length);. the output was LOG: This.length = 1, for the expected number of elements. When I look at the debugger, the objects seem to be initialized properly(name, ids and values I expect) Strange right?

Comment: Could it be that the elements, though found in the dom, arent ready to have an event bound to them?

Comment: @thenorthsider23. No it can not. Try give us the HTML, can a fiddle on jsFiddlt.net is event better.

Comment: thanks so much for the help, Ive never used jsFiddle, but I'll set one up now.

Comment: Is this failing in all browsers or just specific ones?

Comment: have you tried my last solution? any luck?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the following?

```
$(this).live ("change", function() {
    //...
});
```

Comment: Per the documentation. As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers...

Comment: oh! thanks. missed that part. time to update my jQuery version.

Comment: Yea, not many people seem to know that.  jQuery's docs have discouraged using .live() since 1.4 when delegate() came out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using 1.7, so I'm hoping to stick to live. I did try both live(), on() and change() and none seem to work despite the console output!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your HTML sample and jQuery codes. Interestingly, you have used two radio inputs, those two input changes simultaneously or any of them toggles with the change of other one. Simple if you change one's value to 1 then it will automatically changes the other one's value to 0

Also you have used `if ($(this).val() == "1")`  so if one's value changes to 1 and the other changes to 0 as well. So both changes does actually first show then hide, which makes to seem no event fired.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out or remove the `console.log()` line. IE will choke on it unless the developer tools are open when running the script.